# Metric under homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set and $d:X^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a metric on $X$. Thus $(X,d)$ denotes a metric space. Consider a homeomorphism f on $X$ as $f:X \to Y$. My question is whether the same metric $d$ holds  for $Y$. In other words, is $(Y,d)$ a metric space?

A short proof and explanation will be very helpful.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything to talk about a homeomorphism between sets. Do $X$ and $Y$ have topologies? ($X$ has one induces by the metric, but does $Y$ have one a priori?)

Comment: @JohnHughes I think he was just very sloppy, we can say $X$ has a topology due to the metric and if we assume $Y$ has one that makes a homeomorphism possible then the rest follows. I agree though it is very slopy to forget such.

Comment: I am really sorry. I did forget to mention it. Thanks for pointing it out. Ill correct it soon.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no. No because the metric $d$ is only defined for $X\times X$ and not $Y\times Y$ however, it is easily resolved by denoting the induced metric as
$$d^\ast:Y\times Y\to\Bbb R$$
by having
$$d^\ast(x,y)=d(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y))$$
where $f$ is the homeomorphism in question, this of course depends on the homeomorphism and without it you cannot do it as there is no way to define it meaningfully, unless you take the infinitum of all possible homeomorphisms and use the original metric.

So $(Y,d^\ast)$ is a metric space which is depended upon $d$, but $(Y,d)$ is not because the function $d$ is not defined for the set $Y$.

Comment: +1. It's also worth pointing out to the OP that if $d_1, d_2$ are two different metrics on $X$ yielding the same topology, then $d_1^*$ and $d_2^*$ also yield the same topology.

Comment: Well as there is a homeomorphism that is a given, if one has only a bijection the result is what you say. But that is mostly just nitpicking over concepts and orders.